# Registration form validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm getting an error in the console, please give me help.

It is a registration form with JavaScript validation. In it, all the inputs are mandatory and email address entered should be in the correct format.Also, the values entered in the password and confirm password should be the same. And also after validating using javascript, it should display a proper error message in the text box where the error occurred. It is not displaying error messages.

Thanks in Advance.

*html file*

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Registration Form..</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outerContainer">
            <div class="header">
                <h3>Registration Form</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="innerContainer">
                <h5>Registration Form</h5>
                    <form name="registerform">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="first" onKeyup="validate()"> <div id="errFirst"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="last" onkeyup="validate()"> <div id="errLast"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label>e-mail id:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="validate()"> <div id="errEmail"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label>User Id:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="uid" onkeyup="validate()"><div id="errUid"></div> 
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label>Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" id="pwd" onkeyup="validate()"> <div id="errPwd"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" id="confirm" onkeyup="validate()"> <div id="errConfirm"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="button" value="register" id="create" onclick="validate(); finalValidate();"><div id="errFinal"></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                    
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <h5>Copy rights @2017</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*css file*

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.outerContainer {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background:#fffccc;
    background:img;
}
.footer, .header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background:#0000ff;         
}
.footer {
    font-size: 11px;
    clear:both;
    font-style:Mistral;             
}       
.innerContainer{
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    height:400;
    overflow: scroll;       
    padding: 5px;
    background-image:url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-abstract-background-with-lights_1048-3309.jpg");                   
}
form{
    background:#ffccaa;
    display-block:center;
}
h5{
    text-align:center;
    color:#ff23ff;              
}
label{
    color: #464646;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

*javascript file*

```
 var divs=new Array();
divs[0]="errFirst";
divs[1]="errLast";
divs[2]="errEmail";
divs[3]="errUid";
divs[4]="errPwd";
divs[5]="errConfirm";

function validate(){
    var inputs=new Array();
    inputs[0]=document.getElementById('first').value;
    inputs[1]=document.getElementById('last').value;
    inputs[2]=document.getElementById('email').value;
    inputs[3]=document.getElementById('uid').value;
    inputs[4]=document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    inputs[5]=document.getElementById('confirm').value;
    var errors= new Array();
    errors[0]="<span>Please enter your First name!</span>";
    errors[1]="<span>Please enter your Last name!</span>";
    errors[2]="<span>Please enter your e-mail-id!</span>";
    errors[3]="<span>Please enter your User Id!</span>";
    errors[4]="<span>Please enter your Password!</span>";
    errors[5]="<span>Please enter your Confirm Password!</span>";
    for(i in inputs){
        
        var errMsg=errors[i];
        var divMsg=divs[i];
        if(inputs[i]=="")
            
            document.getElementById(divMsg).innerHTML=errMsg;
            
        else if(i==2){
            var atpos=inputs[i].indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=inputs[i].lastIndexOf(".");
            if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>= inputs[i].length)
                document.getElementById('errEmail').innerHTML="<span>Enter Valid e-mail adderss!!</span>";
            else
                document.getElementById(divMsg).innerHTML="OK!";
        }else if(i==5){
            var ff=document.getElementById('pwd').value;
            var ss=document.getElementById('confirm').value;
            if(ss!=ff)
                document.getElementById("errConfirm").innerHTML="<span>Your password doesnot match..!!</span>";
            else
                document.getElementById(divMsg).innerHTML="OK!";
        }else
            document.getElementById(divMsg).innerHTML="OK!";
    }
    
}
    
    function finalValidate()

    {

         var count = 0;

        for(i=0;i<6;i++)

        {

          var divMsg = divs[i];

          if(document.getElementById(divMsg).innerHTML == "OK!")

               count = count + 1;

        }

       if(count == 6)

         document.getElementById("errFinal").innerHTML = "All the data you entered is correct!!!";
        else
            document.getElementById("errFinal").innerHTML="Please enter all the required fields.!!";

    }
```

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: Is any of that CSS relevant to the question? Regarding your error, please [edit] your question to tell us what it is. (Also, if the console reports an error you should be able to click the line number in the error message to be taken to the line where the error occurred. Possibly the one where you put `vat` instead of `var`.)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of typos in code because of which you got error in console,

In HTML file,

```
<div id="errLirst"></div>
```

Change the ID value to **errLast** like you have given in JS file

```
 document.getElementById("divMsg").innerHTML="OK!";
```

Remove the quotes for the **divMsg** id, since divMsg is a variable

In JS File,

```
vat dotpos=inputs[i].lastIndexOf(".");
```

Declarative type for the variable dotpos is **var** not var.

Comment: Thank you ..validation is done till here.. but after inserting another function it is not doing validation..

Comment: What's your exact error? On clicking register, finalvalidate() runs and gives the correct output